# Inserting diacritics after the letter?

Tags: macos, keyboard, diacritics, keyboard-layout, hammerspoon

To write words with diacritics, like café or αὐτοῖς, one usually must press the [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) **before** the letter, like this: caf[option+e]e > caf´e > café. It's a strange choice, on a paper no one would have written the diacritic first.

How can I write the opposite: first the letter, then the dead key: cafe[´]?

Some keyboard layouts do support this, e.g. in Hebrew writing א and then ָ results in the correct אָ.

Every method would be welcomed: Maybe something in Mac OS settings, or using something like hammerspoon, or creating a new keyboard layout.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using an utility called aText to do exactly that - write French diacritics in a non-French keyboard layout on the Mac, in the method you described. In principle it should be possible in Hammerspoon too, perhaps using the hs.hotkey.modal() interface.